# How to define an ARM assembly function that can be used in C

Tags: assembly, arm, gnu-toolchain

I've learnt C for few months already and now I'm starting to take a deeper look into the lower level language -  ARM assembly, so, I decided to start with a very basic project, making an assembly file .S that defines a factorial function and then calling and using it in C. So I want to ask whether assembly can be used to define such a complicate function and can be used as another functions in C? If you don't mind, please give me a simple example of .S file in which a function loads 2 numbers from standard input num1 and num2 to registers, computes num1*num2 and returns the result is defined and can be used in C source file?

Thank you for reading. If this question is stupid, at least, please give me a direction so that I can follow and find out it by myself.

Comment: The question about calling an asm function from C is not stupid (however, there are loads of info on this that you could find yourself if you tried).   The request to give you pretty much everything is usually not welcomed here - first show your effort, what have you done so far and where are you stuck.   Doing input in assembly is a very impractical idea - it's much easier to do this in C, so what's the point, what will you gain?  Do the input in C, pass it as parameters into the asm function to process and return the result back into your C program. This makes more sense.

Comment: you may want to check the assemply code generated from the compiler. gcc will produce .s output if you use the '-S' flag.

Answer (score 5):

To use a function written in Assembler from C, you mainly need to things:

1. Declare but do not define the function in C.
2. Stick to the ARM calling conventions.

**Declaration**

Declaring is easy, e.g:

```
int add(int a, int b);
```

It's a declaration because it does not include the body of the function. And of course the name (*add* in this case) must match.

If you use it in C++, you must add `extern "C"`:

```
extern "C" int add(int a, int b);
```

**Calling convention**

The calling convention defines how arguments are passed to and returned from a functions and what registers have to be saved. You'll need to get familiar with the details. A simplified overview can be found at [ARM (A32) calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention#ARM_(A32)).

A super short and very simplified version is:

- The first four arguments are passed in R0 to R3, the rest is passed on the stack.
- The return values is returned in R0.
- The registers other than R0 to R3 must be saved and restored.

A simple implementation for the above function is:

```
add:
        add     r0, r0, r1
        bx      lr
```

`a` is passed in R0, `b` is passed in R1. The result is returned in `R0`. Registers above R3 are not saved and restored as they are not touched.

A more extensive version looks like this:

```
add:
        str     fp, [sp, #-4]!
        add     fp, sp, #0
        sub     sp, sp, #12
        str     r0, [fp, #-8]
        str     r1, [fp, #-12]
        ldr     r2, [fp, #-8]
        ldr     r3, [fp, #-12]
        add     r3, r2, r3
        mov     r0, r3
        add     sp, fp, #0
        ldr     fp, [sp], #4
        bx      lr
```

It's basically the *debug* version of the *add* function: space is allocated on the stack to store `a` and `b` as local variables and the frame pointer register (fp) points to the local variables. At the end, everything is restored.

Answer (score 0):

Most sane compilers compile to assembly then call the assembler to turn that into an object.

```
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
    return((a<<1)+(b^0xFF));
}

arm-none-eabi-gcc -O2 -c so.c -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D so.o

00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e22110ff    eor r1, r1, #255    ; 0xff
   4:   e0810080    add r0, r1, r0, lsl #1
   8:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

I find this the easiest way to read the output even though I am allowing it to be assembled.

But you can do this

arm-none-eabi-gcc -O2 -S so.c -o so.s

or

arm-none-eabi-gcc -O2 -c -save-temps so.c -o so.o

and look at so.s

```
     cat so.s
    .cpu arm7tdmi
    .eabi_attribute 20, 1
    .eabi_attribute 21, 1
    .eabi_attribute 23, 3
    .eabi_attribute 24, 1
    .eabi_attribute 25, 1
    .eabi_attribute 26, 1
    .eabi_attribute 30, 2
    .eabi_attribute 34, 0
    .eabi_attribute 18, 4
    .file   "so.c"
    .text
    .align  2
    .global fun
    .arch armv4t
    .syntax unified
    .arm
    .fpu softvfp
    .type   fun, %function
fun:
    @ Function supports interworking.
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
    @ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    @ link register save eliminated.
    eor r1, r1, #255
    add r0, r1, r0, lsl #1
    bx  lr
    .size   fun, .-fun
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 8.2.0"
```

which you could assemble yourself

```
arm-none-eabi-as so.s -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D so.o

so.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e22110ff    eor r1, r1, #255    ; 0xff
   4:   e0810080    add r0, r1, r0, lsl #1
   8:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

and get the same object as if you didnt do the steps separately.  which also means you could just write your own function in assembly and link it in to a project in the same way you would a C compiled object.

```
    .global fun
fun:
    eor r1, r1, #255
    add r0, r1, r0, lsl #1
    bx  lr

arm-none-eabi-as so.s -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D so.o

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e22110ff    eor r1, r1, #255    ; 0xff
   4:   e0810080    add r0, r1, r0, lsl #1
   8:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

Comment: assembly language is defined by the assembler, the tool, not the target.  But it is not uncommon, and certainly with gas, to have labels be local unless declared as global, unlike C where the label (variable/function name) is global unless declared local (static).  some compilers mangle the labels, some dont so the main exercise is for your toolchain/assembler do you need to declare the label global and do you need to mangle it.

Comment: also note that if you want to do thumb then it is a good idea that you use .thumb_func before function labels (will apply itself to the next label it sees doesnt have to be the next line of code).